# Animate a parametric curve

Tags: plotting, animation

How can I animate the following curve?

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[Sqrt[2] t](3 + Cos[t]), Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), Sin[t]},
  {t, 0, 50}
]
```

Can I also remove the coordinate box?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to generate the line as in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfKxzKM-MNc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `Manipulate` as it is just like `Animate` but more flexible.

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{t},
  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), 
    Sin[Sqrt[2] t] (3 + Cos[t]), Sin[t]},
   {t, 0, maxTime},
   ImageSize -> 300,
   PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-1, 1}},
   PlotStyle -> Red]
  ]
 ,
 {{maxTime, 1, "time"}, 1, 50, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {maxTime}
 ]
```

To removed the box and the axis, look at options `Boxed -> False` and  `Axes -> False`

In Manipulate, you decide which are the control variables in your expression. For each one, you add a control variable definition in the body of the Manipulate. In this case, there is only one control variable.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. Can I run the time automatically?

Comment: @AbdelRahmanAl-Amrat Yes. Open the  Manipulate control (click on the small + thing on the  right side of the slider) and click on the `>` button to play it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Animate[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[Sqrt[2]t], Sin[Sqrt[2]t] (3 + Cos[t]), Sin[t]}, {t, 0, tmax},
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1], 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-2 Pi, 2 Pi}, {-1.1, 1.1}}] /. 
    Line -> ({CapForm[None], FaceForm[Opacity[.5, Blue], Yellow], Tube[#, .1]} &), 
 {tmax, 1, 50, .01}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again kglr!

Comment: @AbdelRahman, you are welcome.